# Is there any way to deploy a Wp7 app to a phone without publishing or using Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I have a Wp7 app (ready in a xap), and I'd like to give it to a client, so he can use it in 5-10 devices. But it is an "internal" client for our service, so I'd rather **not publish it on WP Marketplace** for all to see...

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you upload app on marketplace you can set it as private so only users with direct link can see/install it. There was an app which hacked WP7 that allows you to install apps without marketplace but I've heard it's not legal anymore*.

*search for it because I'm not sure about this one.

edit: http://www.electronista.com/articles/12/01/02/chevronwp7.runs.out.of.tokens.may.not.renew/

Comment: This is what my research turned up also. I was kinda hoping I missed something...

Comment: It's perfectly legal. The developers have stopped selling the unlock codes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try http://labs.chevronwp7.com/

EDIT : Sorry, it seems that all tokens are sold out, so this is not solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, you can publish a application on the marketplace as a beta, allowing 5 users to test it using their Live IDs.

But all unlocked phones can have a XAP installed. Generally, Windows Phone applications aren't designed for internal distribution. If you don't intend to publish the application on the marketplace at any point, you need to estimate in the cost of $100 per phone, per year, for the usage of your application.

I'll recommend you contact Microsoft, if you need a specialized deal.